# Sprachwandel oder weit verbreiteter Misnomer von "komplex"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Es ist mir inzwischen des Öfteren nicht entgangen, dass sich Leute des Begriffes "komplex" bedient haben, obwohl in betroffenem Kontext eher "kompliziert" gemeint war. Es ist selbstverständlich weder die komplexitätstheoretische Bedeutung, noch ein Bezug zu komplexen Zahlen gemeint.

Liegt bei all jenen ein Misnomer vor? Oder ist es zu akzeptieren, dass sich die Sprache in dieser Beziehung wandelt? Ist es denn in eurem Umfeld vergleichbar oder ist dies region- / dialektbedingt?

Zur Differenzierung favorisiere ich diese treffende Erklärung:

> Nicht zu verwechseln mit komplex, obwohl es in nahem Zusammenhang mit der Komplexität steht. Es ist ein impliziter Komparativ zwischen dem, was man gerne hätte und dem, was man hat. Objektiv ist etwas kompliziert, wenn es eine unnötig hohe Komplexität bzw. Vielschichtigkeit aufweist. Subjektiv erscheint etwas als kompliziert, wenn man nicht über das Wissen, das Können, die Intelligenz oder die Bereitschaft verfügt, es zu verstehen oder zu beherrschen. Daher ist Kompliziertheit immer negativ konnotiert. Diese Konnotation wird im Sprachgebrauch meist durch zusätzlich abwertende, rein deutsche Worte markiert: "zu kompliziert", "ziemlich kompliziert". Das wird zur Stilblüte wenn man etwas als "unnötig kompliziert" bezeichnet, weil die Eigenschaft des Unnötigen, nicht Hilfreichen schon im Komplizierten enthalten ist, wohingegen ein mitunter sehr hoher Grad an Komplexität durchaus notwendig sein kann.

http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/kompliziert

Ferner ist mir aufgefallen, dass sich die substantivierte Form von "komplex" intuitiv und natürlich anhört: Komplexität.

Selbes gilt nicht jedoch für "kompliziert". Die substantivierte Form hört sich - für mich zumindest - sehr künstlich an: Kompliziertheit.

Würde das Wort "komplex" nun neu die Bedeutung von "kompliziert" übernehmen, so fehlte ein prägnanter Begriff zur Verdeutlichung von Vielseitigkeit, Vielfältigkeit, (objektiver) Kompliziertheit und Schwierigkeit, da all diese nicht dasselbe ausdrücken, wie es "komplex" tun würde. Von der Tatsache abgesehen, dass sie sind noch nicht einmal alle Abstrakta sind.

Comment: Beispiele oder gar Quellen würden helfen, die Frage und damit auch die Antworten zu konkretisieren. Mir z.B. fallen zwar entsprechende Situationen ein, ein regelrechter Wandel ist mir jedoch nicht aufgefallen.

Comment: Die Frage ist komplex. Äh, kompliziert?

Comment: Ist "Misnomer" das rechte Wort?

Comment: @Carlster Das fällt mir dementsprechend schwer, da ich auf alltäglichen Gebrauch referiere. Würde es mir online irgendwo auffallen, so nur in beispielsweise Foren.

@ CarstenSchultz Wäre es schon, wenn die Benutzer das Wort als "kompliziert" verstehen und es daher auch so verwenden. Nichtsdestotrotz ist "Misnomer" ein Anglizismus, jedoch konnte ich mich noch mit keinem deutschen Wort abfinden. Missdeutung? Fehldeutung? Oder gar ein Neologismus wie Falschverständnis? Es geht bei Misnomern ja darum, dass der Einzelne ein falsches Verständnis dafür hat: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misnomer

Comment: Duden führt die zwei als nicht synonym, es werden auch keine regionalen Ausnahmen erwähnt. Wiktionary stimmt dem offenbar zu und dir fallen keine Beispiele ein. Überdies haben die Personen (deiner Einschätzung nach) in allen Fällen das falsche Wort verwendet - hat sich die Frage damit nicht erübrigt?

Comment: @Carlster Ich fragte ja explizit nach euren Eindrücken im Alltag in euren Regionen / Dialekten. Denn nur weil das in Wörterbüchern nicht manifestiert wurde, so können dennoch Abweichungen vorhanden sein. Und nur weil euch dies in den euren Umfeldern nicht aufgefallen ist, so könnte es dennoch Leute geben, die mir beipflichten und einen Erfahrungsbericht ablegen könnten.

Comment: Während die Frage offen lässt um welchen Zeitraum es sich handelt, scheint mir jedoch eine google ngram Suche für die letzten 200 Jahre trotzdem interessant: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=komplex%2Fkompliziert&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28komplex%20/%20kompliziert%29%3B%2Cc0 (man ersetze / durch , um die beiden Worte als einzelne Kurven zu sehen, oder hänge jeweilse _INF an die worte an um abgeleitete formen zu sehen. Vor allem dieses lässt einen gewissen Schluss zum Wandel zu)

Comment: Soweit ich das in meiner Umgebung beobachten kann, werden Begriffe sehr oft in dieser Art 'missbraucht' und sind so auch in die Umgangssprache eingegangen; gute Beispiele sind z.B. "biologisch" (wobei das mittlerweile auch wikitionary steht), "Energie verbrauchen" (geschlossenes Energiesystem!) und "Kalorien verbrennen" (man hat kein Feuer in sich).  Komplex hätte ich auch in etwa mit kompliziert gleich gesetzt, ich glaube auch nicht, dass mein näherer Bekanntenkreis den Unterschied wüsste.

Comment: Spannend ist eine kürzeste Antonym-Verbindung bei wiktionary: komplex != simpel, simpel != kompliziert. Wenn ich das nicht missinterpretiere lässt genau dieses Verhältnis auf eine eventuelle synonyme Verwendung schließen!? Gekommen bin ich darauf weil ich `komplex` als Antonym für trivial bestätigt haben wollte (und bekam).

Comment: @FranzEbner != ist hier keine gute Wahl.

Comment: In meinem Umfeld ist vor allem Misnomer ein Alien.

Comment: Aus der Region Ost-Österreich kann ich keine synonyme Verwendung oder auffallend häufige Verwechslung dieser beiden Wörter melden. Ich beobachte aber, im Gegensatz zu der Häufigkeitsverteilung in PlasmaHHs Ngram, dass in der gesprochenen Umgangssprache »kompliziert« häufiger verwendet (und auch gemeint) wird als »komplex«.

Comment: Apropos "immer negativ konnotiert": Ich wünsche mir schön komplizierte Sudokus. Dass schlichte Geister mit Kompliziertheit auf Kriegsfuß stehen und in der Überzahl sind, erklärt diesen Irrtum des Wiktionarys.

Comment: ich vermisse in der Frage das Fragezeichen. Was genau willst Du wissen? Oder beklagst Du Dich hiermit über die Gesellschaft ?

Answer (score 4):

Komplex bezieht sich auf eine Struktur, auf eine Summe von Objekten oder Ideen, die irgendwie zusammenhängen oder zusammen einen Verbund oder Ähnliches bilden. Ein Komplex kann durchaus einfach oder kompliziert sein.

Kompliziert bedeutet, dass es nicht einfach ist. Gegenteil von trivial.

Man verwendet *sehr* komplex oder *stark* komplex oder *zunehmend* komplex, wenn eine Struktur sich auf eine komplizierte Weise weiterentwickelt.

Answer (score 0):

- Duden führt die zwei als nicht synonym.
- Wiktionary stimmt dem offenbar zu.
- Auch in meinem sprachlichen Umfeld ist eine gleichsame Verwendung nicht üblich.

Zu beachten ist, dass Komplexität für bestimmte Beobachter Kompliziertheit implizieren kann.
Sie "dürfen" also beide Wörter verwenden. Steht jedoch fest, dass sie den jeweils anderen Aspekt ausdrücken möchten, handelt es sich um eine Fehlbezeichnung (Misnomer?).